# How to match pattern at the end of line/text

Tags: bash, sed

I am very new to bash. So if this is a pretty basic question, please pardon me.

I am trying to replace file extension '`.gzip`' with '`.gz`'.

E.g.:

```
testfile.xml.gzip => testfile.xml.gz
```

Someone has written a script which does this:

```
GZIP=`echo ${FILE} | grep .gz`

    .
    .
    .

FILE=`echo ${FILE} | sed 's/.gz//g'`
```

The first line wrongly matches `testfile.xml.gzip` file. The `grep .gz` matches the text in filename which is in-between, whereas I need it to match only if it is at the end of the filename. Can anyone help me with how to correct this problem? In short, I need to know the expression which matches pattern the end of the line/text.

Comment: Learn POSIX BRE's ane ERE's :-) Watch out for `\r\n` Windows newlines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `$` to match the end of the line:

```
FILE=`echo ${FILE} | sed 's/.gz$//g'`
```

Anyway, what this command does is remove the trailing `.gz` extension from the filename, which isn't what you're looking for according to your question. To do that, the answer from dnsmkl is the way to go with `sed`.

Note that since you already have `FILE` in a enviroment variable you can use bash [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) as follows:

```
$ FILE=textfile.xml.gzip
$ echo ${FILE/%gzip/zip}
textfile.xml.zip
```

Comment: Your match pattern, whilst probably usually quite sufficient, is not 100% correct as it will also turn file names like `foobargz` into `fooba`, you need to add `\ ` before the `.` if you want it to literally match the _dot_, otherwise any dots in the pattern will match any character. Alternatively if you don't care about dots then perhaps it would be best to leave them out of the pattern, because, as it is, it is confusing.

Comment: the `g` flag seems a bit superfluous?

Answer (score 7):

End of string is matched by "$" in sed

For example

```
echo 'gzip.gzip' | sed  's|gzip$|gz|g'
```

Output is

```
gzip.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

## should do a while directory of .gzip files

(ls *.gzip | while read line; do mv "$line" "$(basename "$line" .gzip).gz"; done)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rename) may work for you:

```
rename gzip gz *gzip
```